Modify MsExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor attribute in Active Directory
EDIT
Through some testing, I realized the attribute can be modified (using PowerShell) for a mailbox that is moved from the Exchange Online back to Exchange Server.
Is there a way I could cheat the Exchange Server into believing the mailbox is there without moving it somehow?

Exchange Server Hybrid with Exchange Online. All mailboxes in the cloud.
User is a RecipientTypeDetails "RemoteUserMailbox".
On user's AD object, there is MsExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor attribute containing 'Unknown SIDs'.
I am trying to either remove unknown SID descriptors or clear the attribute completely.
$User = get-aduser $DN -Properties msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor 

  

$AccessRule = $User.msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor.access[1] 

$Descriptor = $User.msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor 

$AccessRule 

ActiveDirectoryRights    : CreateChild 
InheritanceType          : All 
ObjectType               : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
InheritedObjectType      : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
ObjectFlags              : None 
AccessControlType        : Allow 
IdentityReference        : <Unknown SID> 
IsInherited              : True 
InheritanceFlags         : ContainerInherit 
PropagationFlags         : None 

$Descriptor.GetType() 

PS C:\Users\ME> $User.msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor.gettype() 

IsPublic    IsSerial      Name                                     BaseType 
--------    --------   ----                                           -------- 
True     False    ActiveDirectorySecurity        System.Security.AccessControl.DirectoryObjectSecurity 


$Descriptor.RemoveAccessRuleSpecific($AccessRule) 


#Here SDDL changes, type stays the same 


PS C:\Users\ME> set-aduser -Identity $User.DistinguishedName -Replace @{msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor=$descriptor} 

  

set-aduser : Insufficient access rights to perform the operation 
At line:1 char:1 
+ set-aduser -Identity $a.DistinguishedName -Replace @{msexchmailboxsec ... 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=CHONG Bao Sw...=bollore,DC=com:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8344,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser 

PS C:\Users\ME> set-aduser -Identity $User.DistinguishedName -Replace @{msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor=$descriptor.sddl} 

set-aduser : Insufficient access rights to perform the operation 
At line:1 char:1 
+ set-aduser -Identity $User.DistinguishedName -Replace @{msexchmailboxsec ... 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=CHONG Bao Sw...=bollore,DC=com:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8344,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser 

  PS C:\Users\ME> set-aduser -Identity $User.DistinguishedName -clear msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor 

set-aduser : Insufficient access rights to perform the operation 
At line:1 char:1 
+ set-aduser -Identity $User.DistinguishedName -clear msexchmailboxsecurit ... 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=CHONG Bao Sw...=bollore,DC=com:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8344,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser 

I can modify any other attribute. When I try to modify this one using the editor:


You could try to use ADSIEdit to modify the attribute.

Open ADSIEdit (run adsiedit.msc).
Connect to the appropriate naming context.
Navigate to the user's object.
Right-click the user object and select "Properties."
Locate the msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor attribute.
Attempt to clear or manage the attribute from here.

I have found a similar issue to yours and you can refer to.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/784912/there-is-no-editor-registered-to-handle-this-attri

Same error using ADSIEdit :(

“Is there a way I could cheat the Exchange Server into believing the mailbox is there without moving it somehow?”
You could try to manipulate the attributes msExchRemoteRecipientType that Exchange Server uses to recognize mailbox locations to see if it works.

Thanks, I'll try that.

Hope it helps! Looking forward to the update.

We are still waiting for a comment from Exchange Lead.

Okay, I will continue to test this issue and if I find a solution I will share it with you!

Ultimately, removing unknown SIDs from Foreign SIDs OU did the trick without a need to mangle with Exchange. Just took some time before we could see it.

Gald to hear that. Thanks for sharing.
